# Check distance from left side of page accurately?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an element that sometimes (randomly) decides to position incorrectly, which should be centered.  It's currently using CSS.  I am -beyond- lost at how to fix it appropriately, so instead I just want to work around it at this point by checking distance from left and right sides of the page and making sure they are equal.  The parent div takes up 100% of the browser window, always.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
distanceLeft = $('#element').offset().left;
distanceRight = $(window).width()-$('#element').width()-distanceLeft;
```

The problem is that $(window).offset().left is proving to be grossly inaccurate, giving a result something like 45 pixels when in reality it is a couple hundred.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `$(window).offset().left` return 0 generally?

Comment: Typo...should have been '$('#element').offset().left;'

Comment: Can you show an example of this behavior?

Comment: I wish...it's a website for a client and I can't duplicate it no matter how hard I try, but I also can't fix it.

Comment: What are the CSS rules for it? Have you tried top, left, then margin?

Answer (score 0):

try to use reset css in your css page
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

and use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to center an element, usually works fine

Comment: If that worked fine I wouldn't be going through this Javascript ridiculousness. :P